# How to get awk version on macOS?

Tags: macos, awk

I know how to get the version for `awk` on Linux: `awk -W version`

This doesn't work, however, on macOS.

I looked around on SO and couldn't find anything.

I also looked in the `awk` man page and couldn't find anything:

```
$ man awk | grep version
          conversion format used when converting numbers (default %.6g)
   There are no explicit conversions  between  numbers  and  strings.   To
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **EASY** way when `-v`, `-V`, `-version` or `--version` are available (this option is available in most of cases):

```
awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

or

```
awk -version
awk version 20070501
```

Now when it is not available, we go the **hard** way:

```
whereis awk
/usr/bin/awk
```

then

```
what /usr/bin/awk 
/usr/bin/awk
    PROGRAM:awk  PROJECT:awk-24
```

and

```
strings /usr/bin/awk | grep -Ei "version|awk" 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/awk/awk-24/src/b.c
version 20070501
bin/awk
-version
--version
awk %s
awkdelete
weird printf conversion %s
can't happen: bad conversion %c in format()
out of memory in awksprintf
out of memory in awkprintf
@(#)PROGRAM:awk  PROJECT:awk-24
```

You find most all the information you were looking for by reading the strings in the binary and by using `grep` to isolate what you are really looking for.
(Side note you have also find out that `-version` and `--version` are arguments that can be used)

You can also use `grep -Eai "\bversion\b|awk|unix" /usr/bin/awk` to reach the same result (little less readable)

Comment: Appreciate how comprehensive this is! I'd never seen output for version like `awk version 20070501` so I was wondering if there was a way to get something more ample, hence my question.

Comment: As of 2023-02-01 it is `awk version 20200816` and `PROJECT:awk-35`.

Answer (score 7):

```
awk --version
awk version 20070501
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the vast majority of command-line tools have some kind of `--version`, `-v` or `-V` flag that returns this.